# Is there a way to move my Google Play music to my SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, google-play-music

I have a Motorola Droid Micro.

I'm running out of space on my internal storage because it won't let me install things to the SD card.

Is there a way to move the Google Play music (which takes up 2/3 of the space) to my SD card?

Comment: Have you tried moving the Google Play Music app to the SD card? I can't remember if that moves the data as well, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Just announced: [Google Play Music Now Lets You Specify Where Your Music Is Stored](http://www.cultofandroid.com/46874/google-play-music-now-lets-you-specify-where-your-music-is-stored/0)

> A new Google Play Music update is rolling out now, and it brings with it a number of small but significant new features — one of which is the ability to specify where your downloaded music is stored.
>
> You cannot choose a certain folder, but you can choose between internal storage and an SD card, which lets you free up space on your device itself.
>
> This option won’t appear on devices without SD card support...